# Extract gaps from a List of Range<Date>

Tags: java, algorithm, guava, date-range

I have a list of `Range<Date>` based on the Guava library, they never overlap.

- `2001-01-10` **→** `2001-01-15`
- `2001-01-20` **→** `2001-01-22`
- `2001-01-28` **→** `2001-01-29`

Then, I have a reference range:

- `2001-01-01` **→** `2001-01-31`

I want to find all the *exclusive* gaps between the list and the reference range:

- `2001-01-01` **→** `2001-01-10`
- `2001-01-15` **→** `2001-01-20`
- `2001-01-22` **→** `2001-01-28`
- `2001-01-29` **→** `2001-01-31`

*For this example, the Date objects are simple, but in reality they may vary in format depending on their ChronoUnit.*

**Is there a right way to get this result without too much coding?**

Comment: Can the ranges in the list overlap?

Comment: No, I merge them when they are being added, so the input list is clean.

Comment: FYI: Guava's TreeRangeSet can merge/coalesce them for you. See https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#rangeset for details.

Comment: Right, but I don't think I can merge them with TreeSet because the ranges are backed by database records. I have to merge them accordingly and update the database. The gaps, on the other hand, are not physically stored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My approach would be something like

```
RangeSet<Date> rangeSet = TreeRangeSet.create();
rangeSet.add(referenceRange);
for (Range<Date> range : rangesToRemove) {
  rangeSet.remove(range);
}
for (Range<Date> exclusiveRange : rangeSet.asRanges()) {
   ...
}
```

If you manipulate the range bounds correctly, you should get them in the format you desire.

Comment: Thank you very much. I totally overlooked the RangeSet object.

Answer (score 4):

You can [create](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeRangeSet.html#create())/[build](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableRangeSet.Builder.html#build()) a [RangeSet](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeSet.html) from your list of `Range<Date>` and use its [complement()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeSet.html#complement()) with [subRangeSet(Range)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeSet.html#subRangeSet(com.google.common.collect.Range)) to get the exclusive gaps in your reference range:

```
RangeSet<Date> exclusiveRangeSet = rangeSet.complement().subRangeSet(referenceRange);
```